# HTML VBS Special Character handling

Tags: html, vbscript

I have a file that uses a website to do a specific query and returns the data needed via HTML headers. When writing the returned data back to the file with the SQL query that is supplied it works fine. If the query has special characters in it, it stops at that point.

Examples of characters that cause the problem are "?", "~", "_". I have tried to find several work arounds for the data that is coming back but have yet to determine a new means that functions.

This is currently how I am exporting the data when it comes back:

```
Set objExportFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(exportFileLocation, 8, True, -1)
objExportFile.Writeline(objHead.responseText)
objExportFile.Close
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'd try writing a character at a time and see if it stops somewhere specifically, run this with cscript.exe instead of wscript.exe:

```
Set objExportFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(exportFileLocation, 8, True, -1)

sCharacterData = ""
sCharacterData = objHead.responseText 'write the response to a variable
wscript.echo("Character Length of sCharacterData: " & Len(sCharacterData))

vCharNumber = 0 'set the index

Do Until vCharNumber > Len(sCharacterData) 'loop through all the characters
  sCurrentChar = Mid(sCharacterData, vCharNumber, 1)
  wscript.write("CharNumber: " & vCharNumber & " Char: " & sCurrentChar)

  objExportFile.Write(sCurrentChar) 'write 1 character
  vCharNumber = vCharNumber + 1 'increment index
Loop

objExportFile.Close
```

Comment: getting an error message that MID isnt a function basically, dont know if I need to include something I am not currently.

Comment: Paste the exact message or a screenshot. Mid is a built in function of VBScript.

Comment: Script: \\scriptlocation.vbs
Line: 136
Char: 3
Error: Invalid Procedure call or argument: 'mid'
Code: 800a0005
Source: Microsoft VBScript Runtine Error

line 136: sCurrentChar=mid(scharacterdata, vcharnumber, 1)

Comment: I'm guessing sCharacterData is uninitialized. See the code changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
Dim BadChar(2)
Dim Char
Dim header
BadChar(0) = "?"
BadChar(1) = "~"
BadChar(2) = "_"

header = objHead.responseText
For Each Char in BadChar
 If InStr(header, Char) Then
  header = replace(header, Char, "")
 End If
Next
Set objExportFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(exportFileLocation, 8, True, -1)
objExportFile.Writeline(header)
objExportFile.Close
```

Comment: THe error message I got was Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'objhead.reponseText'

@Dan